# Flutter web app wont load when firestore is implemented

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I was trying to add cloud firestore to my app. Everthing works perfectly fine but when I try to add firestore the app wont load. Its just stuck here and shows a white screen:

```
[0]: Web Server (web-server)
[1]: Chrome (chrome)
[2]: Edge (edge)
Please choose one: [0|1|2]: 1
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Syncing files to device Chrome...                                       
13.642ms (!)
```

yes I registered the app on firebase yes I changed the index.html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "//CENSORED//",
    authDomain: "//CENSORED//",
    databaseURL: "//CENSORED//",
    projectId: "//CENSORED//",
    storageBucket: "//CENSORED//",
    messagingSenderId: "//CENSORED//",
    appId: "//CENSORED//:web://CENSORED//",
    measurementId: "//CENSORED//"
  };
```

and I added everything to the pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^18.2.47-beta
  firebase_auth_web: ^0.1.3+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
```

No errors are thrown it just doesnt load.

Comment: You forgot to add `firebase_core`

Comment: already tried that but then i get this error: `[project] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in project...                       
Because project depends on firebase_core ^0.15.2 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because project depends on firebase_core ^0.15.2 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.)
exit code 1`

Comment: There is no version 0.15.2 for `firebase_core`

Comment: But what version should I use then? I used 0.15.2 because I found it here: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_web  "This package is the endorsed implementation of firebase_auth for the web platform since version 0.15.2, so it gets automatically added to your dependencies by depending on firebase_core: ^0.15.2."

Comment: nvm found the right version myself on pub.dev. But I think they have to replace that 0.15.2 with firebase_core: ^0.4.5 right?

Comment: But adding firebase_core didnt solve the problem. Its still not loading and showing a white screen

Comment: No need to init your Firebase Config over an scrip... it's been a while since you can do that over Dart right after your runApp method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that even though you have added the `cloud_firestore` dependency you didn't include its js cdn in index.html.

i.e. you have included `firebase-app`, `firebase-auth`, and `firebase-analytics`. So the same way you need to add the cdn file of `firebase-firestore` to use it.

I don't think you need the `firebase-core` dart package. I have used firebase for many of my projects and everything works fine without the `firebase-core` package.

Comment: Thx for your help but I included its js cdn in the index.html as I said in my post. I also manually added the firebase_auth_web later but its still not working. Also acording to the package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_web it should automatically get added when I add firebase_core.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Just a question, you want to use firestore then why are you referring to `firebase_auth`? And the code for `index.html` you have provided in your question doesn't include the cdn for `firebase-firestore`.

Comment: Add this to your `index.html`, `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>`

Comment: Tried that but the website still wont load. I can even remove firestore from the pubspec.yaml and it still wont load. So I guess the problem has to be somewhere in the auth process. But when I completely remove firebase everything works fine